# Error changing root password in memsql

Tags: singlestore

I was trying to change my admin password using
​

`memsql-ops memsql-update-root-password -p <password>`

but i get this error
​

> J543a0b [ERROR] Could not deobfuscate password
>   ​

Any thing i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What does memsql-ops version return?

Answer (score 1):

Use `change-root-password` command:

For Example

```
$ sudo memsqlctl change-root-password --password "NewSecurePass"
```